# IOError: [Errno 22] while trying to write file

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I'm currently trying to download mp3 files from an external server. I've downloaded a 104 songs. However, my program fails on one song. The title of the file is

> "Weird Al" Yankovic - Ode To A Superhero (Parody of "Piano Man" by Billy Joel).mp3

The lines of code that fail are these

```
mp3file = urllib2.urlopen(url)
output = open(filename, 'wb')
output.write(mp3file.read())
```

The passed file path is

> C:\Users\GTX980\Music\Music\"Weird Al" Yankovic - Ode To A Superhero (Parody of "Piano Man" by Billy Joel).mp3

It gives the error from the title. Here it is in full

> IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:\Users\GTX980\Music\Music\"Weird Al" Yankovic - Ode To A Superhero (Parody of "Piano Man" by Billy Joel).mp3'

As I've said before, there's currently 104 songs downloaded. I use `.replace('/', '-')` to remove any path confusion from the files. How should i proceed.

Comment: check file path contains any `\t` tab as character

Comment: @VivekSable As you can see, the file name doesn't. As mentioned before, I've also downloaded 104 files before this, and I have taken care of those problems.

Comment: ok, got now, Thank you @Mischa Arefiev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `"` character is to blame.  Quoting http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177506

> A filename cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ?
>   " < > |

I do not have a Windows box at hand to check this, but all other characters seem to be OK.

Comment: That was the problem. I should have realized that a while ago. Thank you for helping though!

Comment: I was going to, but there's a countdown on for me, so I had to wait.